# C# Aperiodic Event Generation

Tags: c#, winforms, events, alerts

i have a list of events "Appointments" in my database, like at 3:00pm etc, and they have irregular intervals like one after 15 mins and next after 30 mins and next after 25 mins. One way is that i run a thread/timer that checks the database every minute whether it is the minute of next appointment or not.. i want some other mechanism by which i can trigger an alert/event/action on the next saved time that is in my database... how to do it...

Comment: I keep reading this as "C# Aphrodisiac Event Generation" :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the date/time of the next appointment in the database, subtract from that DateTime.Now in order to get a TimeSpan, and then use that timespan to fire the timer once, similar to this:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void FireTimerAt(DateTime next)
    {
        TimeSpan waitTime = next - DateTime.Now;

        new Timer(delegate(object s) {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}",
                        DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff"), s);
                    }
              , null, waitTime, new TimeSpan(-1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

From the [Features of Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html):

> Quartz.NET can run embedded within another free standing application

Comment: i need to implement it in C# with in my application, other standalone or any other kind of systems wont work...

Comment: Quartz.NET can also run within your application as it's a library for scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

[Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

> Provides a mechanism for executing a
>   method at specified intervals. This
>   class cannot be inherited.